# How to include needed headers automatically in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, header, include, qt-creator

I have a project in Qt Creator, and I want that the header files be included automatically when using a new object.

It's like in Eclipse: Add needed headers when invoking a new object by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt+Space</kbd>.

Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>  /* Header that i want to include automatically */

 int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv) ;
    QWidget fenetre;
/*Add needed headers when invoking a new object like ctrl+alt+space in eclipse*/
    QPushButton bouton( "Bonjour", &fenetre) ;
    bouton. move(70,60);
    fenetre. show( ) ;
    return app. exec( ) ;
}
```

Comment: No, but if you want to include a larger subset (almost everything) you can try for something like, #include <QtWidgets> and #include <QtCore> for example

Comment: Yes it possible but not the solution if there is a lot of lines of code !!!

Comment: "Yes it possible but not the solution if there is a lot of lines of code !!!" It doesn't really matter in practice unless you *project* has many files. Personally I find that for small projects (<100 files) you're perfectly fine including everything. But even for large projects (1000s of files), precompiled headers make all the difference: use them! They'll make including the entire Qt modules have essentially zero cost.

Comment: OTOH, you must be dealing with really trivial code if manually typing this out makes any real difference. Suppose you have a "typical" source module between 1k-5k lines. What's a dozen or two include lines? Noise.

Comment: Anyone who has developed for some time in Java knows that this is gold, and excluding this feature from QtCreator is crippling at best. Another similar feature is that the needed imports are carried with any code you copy and paste between files so that you don't have to do that manually

Answer (score 5):

In Qt Creator version 4.1.0, you have an option for that:

- Move your cursor over the type you want to include
- Right click
- choose *Refactor*

The Shortcut for that is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to trigger quick fix, you can see what is the shortcut for it if it does not work on your machine `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` (Search for *Quick fix*).

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly as you requested, but: if you would like to create a new class with the help of Qt Creator you can certainly have Qt Creator taking care of immediate include files as well:

[image]

[Qt Documentation: Creating Projects](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-creating.html).